# how to get an applet value in json as output

Tags: java, json, applet

I have an applet code that displays my name in the applet browser. Now am trying to get my name as json output inside the same applet. Below is my code,

```
public class AppletClass extends Applet{  
   public void paint(Graphics g){
      String name = "Myname";
      JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(); // assigning json
      obj.put("MyName",name);
   }
   g.drawString(name,40,20);
}
```

When i excute am getting my name in browser but there is no response from json and am not sure how to get it. Could anyone suggest an idea to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file create a function that accepts a parameter, in your applet code pass the json object to this function.